# Does C++11 specify the construction sequence of static/global variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, static, global

In C++98/03, the construction of static objects(in files, in classes, in functions) has no specified sequence, one static object cannot assume it's constructed after or before another static object, seem to be decided by linker.

My question is, does C++ 11/14 specify any rules for the construction sequences of static objects and global objects?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but call_once (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) gives you a way to be specific.

Comment: No, nothing changed in the meantime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules have not changed.  However all global/static objects are constructed in the order they appear in the translation unit.  It is just the order of initialization of multiple translation units that is unspecified.

Do note that function local static objects are constructed in a specified manner.  They are constructed the first time the their declaration is reached and live until the end of the program.  This behavior was changed in C++11 though as before C++11 that initialization was not thread safe where C++11 and above specifies that static initialization will be thread safe.

Comment: Function local static objects are constructed the first time the scope containing them is entered, which can be after the first time the function is entered - it can even be on a subsequent call to the function (or not at all) if that scope's controlled by e.g. an `if` condition that isn't true on the first call to the function.

Comment: @TonyD Fixed.  You are right they are only initialized once that initialization is reached.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: Global objects will be constructed in order within a compilation unit. Ando No: Nothing changed with C++11/14.